# Maven archetype to generate simple project including site

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype

Is there a Maven archetype that will generate the same scaffolding as `maven-archetype-quickstart`, but will in addition create the basic project site layout generated by `maven-archetype-site`? Or do I always have to run each in sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I think [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/) is very often the right tool to use when beginning a new Java project.
See the [QuickStart for samples.](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart)

I don't think the site will be generated from the initial AppFuse generation but a simple `mvn site` will create the basic web site.

Answer (score 0):

I know only 2 maven archetypes for site:

- maven-archetype-site
- maven-archetype-simple

I wonder what template they use in Apache.